# A prime ideal of a polynomial ring in 3 variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R = k[a,b,c]$ where $k$ is a field and let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by the polynomial $ac - (b^2 + 1).$ I am considering the quotient ring $$R / I = k[a,b,c] / (ac - (b^2 + 1)).$$
I want to show that this quotient ring is an integral domain.

My first thought is to show that $I$ is a prime ideal of $R$ and then one can conclude that $R/I$ is an integral domain. I am having trouble formulating an argument as to why $I$ is prime in $R$. Any suggestions on how to begin would be appreciated.

Comment: You can try to show the polynomial $ac-(b^2+1)$ is irreducible in $k[a,b,c]$. To do that, we may think of $ac-(b^2+1)$ as a polynomial in $k(a,b)[c]$.

Comment: are there any criterions of irreducibility I should call upon?

Comment: Also how would thinking of  $ac - (b^2 + 1)$ as polynomial in $k(a,b)[c]$ help? Like whats the intuition there?

Comment: If $ac-(b^2+1)= f(a,b,c)g(a,b,c) \in k[a,b,c]$ then by regarding $ac-(b^2+1)$ as element of $k(a,b)[c]$, it is irreducible in $k(a,b)[c]$ so either $f$ or $g$ is a unit in $k(a,b)[c]$. But units in $k(a,b)[c]$ are precisely element of $k(a,b)$. You can proceed from here. (So the idea is that you just remove variable $c$ from $f$ or $g$).

Comment: Once you get that the units in $k(a,b)[c]$ are precisely the elements of $k(a,b)$, what must i do to proceed. Am i trying to run into a contradiction?

Comment: If, say, $f(a,b,c)$ is $f(a,b)$ then $ac-(b^2+1)= f(a,b)g(a,b,c)$ would imply $g(a,b,c)$ is a linear polynomial in $c$.